# Appending Echo [Password Generator]

Tags: bash, osx, echo, random, hex

I am creating a password generator however I am not get the passwords to append properly.

Here is my script

```
i="0"
while [ $i -lt 5 ]
do
    echo -n '#' >> passwords.txt && openssl rand -hex 4 >> passwords.txt && echo -n '/' >> passwords.txt && echo -n 'X' >> passwords.txt
    i=$[$i+1]
done
```

Output

```
#b887e0d0
/X#7093289e
/X#2210cfcd
/X#fd175e1f
/X#0c18fc9e
/X
```

Expected Output

```
#b887e0d0/Z
#7093289e/Z
#2210cfcd/Z
#fd175e1f/Z
#0c18fc9e/Z
```

How can I make it so that it doesn't skip that first line and also so that it runs each command in that order and will write to the passwords txt file as the expected output.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks David King, dhag and lese for all these answers, really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do:

```
for i in {1..5}; do
    printf '#%s/Z\n' "$(openssl rand -hex 4)"
done >passwords.txt
```

I replaced the multiple calls to echo with a single call to
printf. Having the call to openssl wrapped inside a command
substitution has the side effect of making the line ending disappear,
and that newline character was the cause of the badly-placed line breaks
visible in your example.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `openssl` is being 'helpful' and placing a newline at the end of the random string.  You can remove that by piping it through `tr`

```
openssl rand -hex 4 | tr -d '\n'
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) I have been spending a while trying fix this.

Thanks.